# reducing vertical space between environments in footnotes

Tags: spacing, gb4e

The `gb4e` package helps linguists to translate examples. It uses list environments to separate the examples from the main text. The Language Science Press version of this package uses `\ea` and `\eal` as shorthands. (These commands were in the original package but were commented out and declared as use with care). Using the shorthands is much more readable and maintainable. Question: Is there a way to reduce the space between (i) and (ii) in the second footnote (on page 3) so that it looks like (iii) and (iv) but the syntax for writing the examples stays as with (i) and (ii)?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{gb4e}

\usepackage{gb4e}


\makeatletter
\def\eal{\begin{exe}\exnrfont\ex\begin{xlist}[iv.]\raggedright}
\def\ex{\@ifnextchar [{\exnrfont\@ex}{\exnrfont\item\exfont}}
\def\eal{\begin{exe}\exnrfont\ex\begin{xlist}[iv.]\raggedright}
\def\z{\ifnum\@xnumdepth=1\end{exe}\else\end{xlist}\fi}
\def\zl{\end{xlist}\end{exe}}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\exnrfont}{\exfont\upshape}
\newcommand{\exfont}{\normalsize\upshape}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\eal
\ex This is an example.
\ex This is another example.
\zl
\eal
\ex This is an example in another set.
\ex This is another example in another set.
\zl
\blindtext\footnote{
  \blindtext
  \eal
  \ex This is an example.
  \ex This is another example.
  \zl
  \eal
  \ex This is an example in another set.
  \ex This is another example in another set.
  \zl
  \blindtext
  }
\blindtext

\pagebreak

\blindtext
\ea
This is an example.
\z
\ea
This is an example in another set.
\z
\blindtext\footnote{
  \blindtext[1]
  \ea
  This is an example.
  \z
  \ea
  This is an example in another set.
  \z
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam
  nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper,
  felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat
  pede. 
  \ea
  This is an example.
  \ex
  This is an example in another set.
  \z
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. 
  }
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile for me. (Undefined control sequence `\stylepath`.)

Comment: And there are other issues, in the package such as using `\input` instead of `\RequirePackage`, and giving a path name in the `\ProvidesPackage` line. The people at Language Science Press really need to get someone who understands TeX well to do their packages.

Comment: ups sorry, changed this to standard gb4e with commands in the MWE

Comment: Still doesn't compile.  You need to undefine the `\exnrfont` and `\exfont` macros.

Comment: Sorry, incomplete copy & paste.

Comment: I guess the problem is that \ea and \z open and close environments and this causes some space and in footnotes this may be too much since the fonts are smaller anyway. So one would need a way to adjust the spacing according to environment. Just guessing ...

Comment: Give `linguex` a try, it has shortcut macros that might work better than `\ea` and `\z`.

Comment: As far as fixing `gb4e`, TeX provides `\unskip` whose function is to remove spacing (including vertical spacing) that has just been inserted, usually to insert a more appropriate amount. But not all inserted space allows itself to be removed, and it won't work here without further revisions.

Comment: We are using `gb4e` all over the place (in several book projects). Switching to `linguex` is not an option. But thanks for `\unskip`. I will try and integreate this into `\z` in case it detects being in a footnote.